# Excel - Popup Asking for Text w/ Drop Down

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to have a macro that, when pressed, pops up a message box asking for a string of text, and then a drop down that has a list of categories?

All I would need it to do is take this information and save it into a cell. If so, how?

Comment: Sure.  This can be done with a fairly simple combobox form control.  It's a little involved, but there are plenty of helpful tutorials online.  This one is especially good:  http://www.contextures.com/Excel-VBA-ComboBox-Lists.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I'm going based on Excel 2007 here, but if you're using 2003, you'll have to navigate the menu structure]

Go to the VBE (by going to the `View` tab, then click on `Macro` - creating or editing an existing one will take you there - or click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>).

Go to the `Insert` menu, and select `Userform`.  Drag a textbox (the `ab|`icon), and a combobox onto your form.  To set the textbox value to a cell when you change the combobox, create a subroutine in the code to do this by double clicking on the combobox.

Set the combobox items by using the `.additem` method of `comboBox1` in your code.  These can be delineated or grabbed from a range in your code (see [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/add-values-combobox-excel.htm))

Within that subroutine, set the value of whatever cell you want to `textbox1.Text`, which is the contents of the textbox.